# Write excel sheet from DataTable in c#

Tags: c#, excel

How can I write an excel sheet with two field(let them be f1,f2 of a DataTable) in C#?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11797352/export-data-from-datatable-to-excel-file-c-sharp

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `OleDb` components to achieve this using SQL. A sample is given in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57987/writing-into-excel-file-with-oledb).

Please note that to use this with Excel 2003 files, your program must be compiled X86 only, as the JET driver is available for 32-bit only.

To write Excel 2007/10 files, you need to use a different JET driver ([see here](http://www.dotnetspider.com/forum/111574-write-data-into-xlsx-file-using-Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0-provider.aspx)).